# Executing git commits from script

Tags: git, directory, rsync

I want to commit some file from a script to a git server I own, and this needs to be done automatically.

My script (that resides in `~/bin`) does something like this

```
rsync -arE --delete --files-from=~/files.list / ~/repo
git --git-dir ~/repo/.git add ~/repo/*
git --git-dir ~/repo/.git commit -m "automatic commit #123"
git --git-dir ~/repo/.git push
```

I want it to copy the files that are listed in the file `~/files.list` to `~/repo` (rsync handles this) and then add this files to the repository, commit and push.

However, it is unable to correctly add files to the git commit, particularly it always grabs the files that are in the working directory (in this case `~/bin`), so I would need a way to either:

1. change the running directory for the `git` commands **OR**
2. tell git to add files from a directory other than the working one

Comment: You could add a .gitignore. Blacklist everything in bin

Comment: the problem is that it ONLY adds files in ~/bin

Comment: `git add -A` to add everything. Use in conjunction with a .gitignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is Git's `-C` option, which changes the current directory before running. You can write something like the following:

```
rsync -arE --delete --files-from=~/files.list / ~/repo
git -C ~/repo/ add .
git -C ~/repo/ commit -m "automatic commit #123"
git -C ~/repo/ push
```

Of course, you can also write this with as a `cd` and a subshell, but the above may be a little easier:

```
rsync -arE --delete --files-from=~/files.list / ~/repo
(cd ~/repo/ &&
 git add .
 git commit -m "automatic commit #123"
 git push)
```

I assume here that your `rsync` command is already doing what you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

No need to copy, just tell git where your working files are.

```
git -C ~/repo --work-tree="$PWD" add .
git -C ~/repo commit -m etc
git -C ~/repo push
```

Put your `files.list` list in .gitignore format, ignore everything but the files you want git to hunt down, and include it as the repo's `.git/info/exclude`:

```
# To include only this, and/this, and/that but ignore everything else:
# ignore everything
*
# except
!this
!and/this
!and/that
!etc
# do search inside directories, don't let ignores stop later searches inside
!*/
```

A note, the paths on the command line are taken relative to the work tree if you're not already inside it, so if you're in a repo and want to add content from elsewhere you can `git --work-tree=/path/to/elsewhere add .` and it'll add it all.